# IE jQuery Object Doesn't Support Property trim()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

In IE 8 on Prestashop I get the `Object doesn't support property or method` on this line:

`new_li.className = new_li.className.trim();`

The full function:

```
function appendAddressList(dest_comp, values, fields_name)
{
    for (var item in fields_name)
    {
        var name = fields_name[item].replace(",", "");
        var value = getFieldValue(name, values);
        if (value != "")
        {
            var new_li = document.createElement('li');
            var reg = new RegExp("[ ]+", "g");
            var classes = name.split(reg);
            new_li.className = '';
            for (clas in classes)
                new_li.className += 'address_' + classes[clas].toLowerCase().replace(":", "_") + ' ';
            new_li.className = new_li.className.trim();
            new_li.innerHTML = value;
            dest_comp.append(new_li);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm reading that I need to use $.trim(Str) instead, but I'm not sure how to achieve this exactly.

Do I just need to rewrite it like so?

`new_li.className = $.trim(new_li.className);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$.trim(new_li.className);` is correct way.